# Cloning OpenShift repository from domain

Tags: git, repository, clone, openshift, multiple-domains

This problem occurs when I try to clone/import a repository from my company's OpenShift domain using Eclipse. I have a "Can administer" permission on that domain. However, cloning/importing from my personal OpenShift domain isn't a problem, so obviously my SSH keys are working properly. The message I get when I try to clone from my company's domain is

```
    Could not clone the repository. Authentication failed.
    Please make sure that you added your private key to the ssh preferences.
    ssh://5334229ce0b8cd6c830001c1@<<app-name>>-<domain-name>>.rhcloud.com/~/git/eaglepay1.git/: Auth fail
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

#### you must upload your ssh `public key` to the openshift first..

First copy the `public key` some thing in `/home/suhail/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` like:

```
suhail@suaiman-Satellite-L300:~$ cat /home/suhail/.ssh/id_rsa.pub 
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAtlw
elliRcKPvWMpQa9f7PZibelCDh+xZjU4Zwovx/nSSh6CXW
... a really long string.......
```

### Then add it in [openshift](http://www.openshift.com)

ie create a new `publickey` and give a name and then paste it in publickey textbox:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I already have an SSH key uploaded in OpenShift. When I clone from my personal domain, it's fine, but when I try to clone from another domain that I have a "Can administer" role on, I get an "Auth fail" error message from Eclipse.